# D3 v4 xAxis zoom return x as NaN making rescale(x) unable to complete

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to achieve an zoom option with x axis as date format.
Here's the code sample:

```
var margin = {
top: 20,
right: 20,
bottom: 40,
left: 100
  },
  svgWidth = 800,
  svgHeight = 500,
  width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

svg = d3.select('body')
  .append("svg")
  .attr("style", "width: " + svgWidth + "px\; height: " + svgHeight + "px\;");

var x = d3.scaleUtc().range([0, width])
  .domain([new Date("3/12/2017"), new Date("3/30/2017")]);

var y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([height, 0])
  .padding(0.1)
  .domain(["test"])

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.utcFormat("%m-%d"));

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
  .translateExtent([0, 0], [width, height])
  .extent([[0, 0], [width, height]])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var xLine = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
  .attr("class", "xAxis")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "middle");
var yLine = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", 0)")
  .attr("class", "yAxis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("class", "cateName")
  .style("text-anchor", "end");

svg.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
  xLine.call(xAxis.scale(d3.event.transform.rescaleX(x)));
};
```

The idea is very simple, when you pan horizontally, the xAxis will adjust the position. However, when you click the SVG, all labels in x axis will disappear.
I tried to look into it but it seems that my `x` in [source code](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/src/transform.js#L13) is `NaN`.

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?
The JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/amyytnt0/1/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I made a very simple mistake:
The `zoom.translateExtent()` should be in 1 argument, not 2.
So the fix should be:
`zoom.translateExtent([[0, 0], [width, height]])`

Answer found here: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/73#issuecomment-263326469